# Cómo agregar tiempo de validez a un campo de una tabla en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta tabla con temporalidad de transacción:

```
CREATE TABLE Empleado
(
    id CHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    num_seguro INT,
    SysStartTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN NOT NULL,
    SysEndTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN NOT NULL,
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime)
)
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON);
```

lo que necesito es poder registrar el tiempo de validez del campo num_seguro, como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Qué es el _tiempo de validez_ de un campo, o de tu campo en particular? ¿Qué esperas que ocurra con el dato almacenado en el campo antes, durante, o después de su _tiempo de validez_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El versionado de tablas, que Sql Server introduce en la versión 2016, lo que realiza es generar un "histórico" de todos los movimientos que tengan los registros a posteriori de su inserción en la tabla de Empleado.

```
CREATE TABLE Empleado
(
    id CHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    num_seguro INT,
    SysStartTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN NOT NULL,
    SysEndTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN NOT NULL,
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime)
)
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON);
GO
```

Con la sentencia que has declarado, el motor se ha generado una tabla de empleados, pero adicionalmente también ha generado la tabla de versiones, con un nombre automatizado, pues no ha sido declarado en la insert.

[image: Resultado]

Si realizas una insert en la tabla "principal", el resultado solo existe en la misma:

```
Insert into dbo.Empleado (id, nombre, num_seguro)
values
('a1','juan',1);
go
```

Pero cuando realizas una modificación o eliminación del registro, entonces, esta se ve anotada también en la tabla de historial.

```
Update e Set nombre = 'luis' from dbo.Empleado e where e.id = 'a1';
go
Select * From dbo.Empleado;
Select * From [dbo].[MSSQL_TemporalHistoryFor_830626002];
```

[image: Resultado querys]

Ahora bien, **esto no implica que el motor tenga que hacer nada**, en ninguna fase de tiempo relativo a los registros, si no sufren ninguna modificación o borrado. En el caso de que se modifiquen o borren, entonces lo anotará en la tabla de historial. Y si realizamos una select podremos obtener el estado de los registros a determinadas fases de tiempo del mismo. Pero estos no se cambian.

[Versionado de Tabla](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/19/versionado-de-tabla-sql-2016/)

> lo que necesito es poder registrar el tiempo de validez del campo
> num_seguro, como puedo hacerlo?

Eso es lógica sobre un campo. Por tanto lo primero sería, al menos añadir una columna que nos permitiese añadir una fecha o algún campo para poder realizar esa lógica.

```
Alter table dbo.Empleado
Add num_Seguro_FechaExpiracion datetime2;
go
```

Automáticamente al añadir el campo, el motor modificará las dos tablas (principal y versionada)

[image: Cambios en tabla]

[image: Select sobre tablas]

A partir de la anotación en los registros, podrás desarrollar la lógica que requiera esa columna, en función de una automatización, o al aplicar una sentencia al registro, o mediante un trigger, o mediante la infinidad de posibilidades que nos permite TSQL.